# Is it possible to leave canada by train or car unvaccinated and vice versa?

Tags: united-states, canada, immigration, travel, covid-19

Can an unvaccinated Canadian citizen or noncitizen leave the country by car or train and likewise return by car or train?

Comment: Added a U.S. tag because it is relevant to the vice versa since the U.S. is the only country to which one can travel by train or car form Canada. Added "immigration" tag since even temporary visits are typically governed by a body of law known as "immigration law".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only train service between the U.S. and Canada is via Amtrak and its Canadian partner Viarail. Amtrak's [website](https://www.amtrak.com/crossing-the-us-canadian-border) states (as of today):

> In addition to the standard entry documentation requirements, the
> Canadian and United States Governments have several additional
> requirements for travel into Canada and the United States.
>
> Travel into United States: Non-U.S. citizen passengers must be fully
> vaccinated with a U.S.FDA or a WHO approved COVID-19 vaccine. See
> details on the United States Department of Homeland Security website.
>
> Travel into Canada: All passengers must use the ArriveCAN app before
> travel and wear a mask in Canadian stations and on board trains while
> traveling through Canada. Non-Canadian citizens must be fully
> vaccinated and carry the vaccination record that was uploaded into
> ArriveCAN. See details on the Government of Canada and Viarail
> websites, and additional Cantrail thruway bus service to Vancouver
> travel requirements.

The requirements are essentially the same for travel by car between the U.S. and Canada.

Comment: What if you are an US citizen who is international student in canada with a student visa. Would getting back into canada be impossible unvaccinated?

Comment: @Outsider It would appear so.

Comment: I think the restrictions have changed, meaning this is no longer the correct answer as of oct 30th 2022?