# Updated: (Oct 2. 2022) Is it possible to enter Canada unvaccinated?

Tags: canada, covid-19, borders

[This is an update to this question I asked some weeks ag](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83300/is-it-possible-to-leave-canada-by-train-or-car-unvaccinated-and-vice-versa)o. From what I read in the news Canada has [changed its border requirnments](https://globalnews.ca/news/9169335/canada-covid-19-travel-restriction/). **Is it now possible to leave and enter Canada unvaccinated?**

Comment: Based on the article you posted, the answer is Yes (finally). The journalist(s) should have included a link to the official source instead of surveying a few nobodies.